# Shopify Theme App Extension - Fetch Data from my Apps API

Tags: javascript, cors, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I am working on a Shopify App. The connection between my embedded App and the backend works fine but from my theme app extension I can't access my Backend. I keep getting:

`Access to fetch at 'https://04eb-2a02-810d-e80-d840-9881-bdd5-5357-265b.eu.ngrok.io/?shop=shopable-stream.myshopify.com&host=c2hvcGFibGUtc3RyZWFtLm15c2hvcGlmeS5jb20vYWRtaW4/api/test' from origin 'https://shopable-stream.myshopify.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

```js
   fetch(' https://someOtherNR.eu.ngrok.io?shop=myshopname.myshopify.com&host=someNr/api/test', {mode: "cors", method: "GET", headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}}).then(function (response) {
   //    // The API call was successful!
      console.log('success!', response);
   }).catch(function (err) {
      console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
   });
```

My backend has core with any origin enabled though

```js
app.use(cors({ origin: '*' } ) );
```

What am I missing?

I expected the call to go through and my theme app extension being able to fetch data from backend.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call your App from an extension as the extension has no context about your App. It is just, front-end code, so that means of course you get CORS errors. Your app is a different domain. And even if you could CORS in you could not access your App securely for obvious reasons.

So in your extension, make your App calls using a Proxy URL from the App Proxy you setup in your App. That way, your extension is securely able to call your App and return either Liquid or JSON as you wish. That is the way to go.